# Why 'sine' wave of alternating current?

Tags: current

1. Electrons flow straight in a wire; not back and forth like a mass connected to a spring. Then, why is it that we represent the alternating current in sine wave form?
2. We know that adding a diode and a capacitor to an A.C. circuit produces D.C. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zet_BCLWc8mI-hs6-peq_Bo9-oLICSGn But how does a combination of diode and capacitor achieve so?

Disclaimer: I am a student of Physics, and this question has been on mind since last 4-5 years. I've always felt ashamed to ask my teachers as it feels elementary and my friends seem to understand easily.

Comment: Your second question is based on an ideal assumption, but even `|sin(x)|` is regarded as DC.

Comment: I think, it is more correct to say that |sin(x)| has a DC portion - but it is not "regarded as DC".

Comment: Mathematics is a funny thing and the use of any other waveform than a sine wave would cause additional losses due to harmonic generation.  Losses due to magnetic/inductive non-linearity, hysteresis and saturation as well as additional capacitive dialectic losses due to the higher frequency harmonics.  Also at each stage of transformation the waveform would slowly approach a perfect sine wave due to the filtering nature of these losses.  So one just sticks to the sine wave as generated by your rotating machine.

Comment: @TheDude the graph in the third section is wrong, since the current will be zero.  (The capacitor blocks the DC produced by the diode.)  The capacitor is in series.  But for DC conversion, the capacitor has to be in parallel with the resistor.

Answer (score 2):

1. Electrons only flow straight in a wire for D.C.; if a circuit is powered with A.C. voltages, then the electrons actually do flow back and forth like a mass connected to a spring. That's the whole difference between D.C. and A.C.

[image]

([Source](https://www.explainthatstuff.com/electricity.html))

2. That's a very vague question. If you're talking about a graph of a D.C. voltage or current, well then, there shouldn't be *any* "A.C. Factors" by definition. The only thing I can think your teacher may be referring to is perhaps noise, which is in fact alternating, and can appear like "A.C. factors" on a D.C. signal.

If you can clarify your questions a bit more, I'm happy to edit my answer and be more specific.

Comment: My 1st question is now clear of doubts. And as for 2nd question, here's the link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zet_BCLWc8mI-hs6-peq_Bo9-oLICSGn Now, how does adding a diode alongwith a capacitor, make the back-and-forth-moving-electrons to move straight in one direction?

Comment: The image you sent explains it pretty well. The diode will only conduct in one direction - that's why the negative part of the current disappears. Then, the capacitor is what "smooths" it out and makes it constant DC. The resistor isn't needed, but it's good to have it there because at the end of the day, this will be powering some sort of resistive load when it is used.

Comment: The diode part is clear to me. I am unclear about role of capacitor. Capacitor is called a 'A.C. filter' as it filters out the A.C. components (or so I have known. Am I wrong there?) OR as you said capacitor "smooths" out the current and makes it constant D.C. How does it achieve so?

Comment: I also edited the question. See now.  I guess it's somewhat clearer.

Comment: @TheDude  In your above link, the circuit does nothing, because the capacitor blocks all DC, while the diode produces DC.  (After one cycle, the current will remain zero forever.)  If instead you wanted a filtered DC output, with a fairly constant voltage across the resistor, then the capacitor must be connected in parallel with the resistor, not in series as shown.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question.  The answer is actually very elegant.

Start by remembering from trigonometry how the sine is defined and it's relation to circular motion - the unit circle:

[image: unit circle]

Keep in mind that the flow of current is determined by voltage.  As the voltage changes, the flow reverses.  The direction of the push - pull is determined by the voltage at the source.

Most of our power distribution systems convert mechanical energy to electrical energy.  With hydroelectric power, water flowing through turbines turn generators.  Generators produce alternating voltages due to the circular motion of the components around a shaft.  The voltage produced changes through the rotational cycle as the angle between the fixed components and the rotating components changes, and is perfectly described by the sine wave.  The speed of the rotation determines the frequency of the wave.  **This is where the mechanical motion, the mathematics, and the voltages are tied together.**

Power transmission requires high voltages to cover long distances.  At very high voltages, huge amounts of power can travel at manageable currents, so the wires can be or reasonable size.  However these very high transmission voltages are incredibly hazardous and would be impossible for end user use.

Transformers make it possible to step alternating voltages up and down.  The output of turbines can be increased or "stepped up" for transmission, then decreased or "stepped down" by transformers at substations for local distribution, then stepped down again by utility transformers near subscribers for end use.

So the existence of transformers for AC are what make AC suitable for production in power plants, transmission to substations, and distribution to power company customers far from the original source.

So at the most basic level, the sinusoidal voltage curve seen on an oscilloscope at a receptacle in your house is directly tied to the rotation of a generator back at a power plant.  (Obviously a major oversimplification of the modern power grid, your power doesn't trace back to a single generator at a single power plant...)

While alternating currents produced by rotating machinery will naturally be produced in a sinusoidal wave, AC is not defined as sinusoidal;  it is entirely possible to generate other non-sinusoidal alternating currents.

Comment: P.S. Do not connect your oscilloscope directly to the mains outlet.  Use at least an isolating (step down) transformer to protect you and your scope.

Comment: @KalleMP - For people that work with mains voltages, scopes are readily available that can be used safely:  for example this scope is safe for use up to 1000V:  https://www.fluke.com/en-us/product/electrical-testing/portable-oscilloscopes/190-series-ii/fluke-190-ii-190-204

Comment: OP is a physics student and not a mains electrician.

Answer (score 0):

The sine wave is a consequence of the way the AC is produced. When driving a generator you simply cannot directly create DC.

Further it's may important to notice that the electrons are not moving like a mass connected to a spring. If current is positive they move in one if current is negative they move in the other direction, but not representing any sinusoidal motion. The sinusoidal current comes from the amount of electrons - this just as a sidenote.

One of the reasons we mainly use AC is due to the fact of easy transformation. In the early (really early) beginning everything started with DC, but when transmitting DC the losses are way higher then with high voltage AC.

Comment: Transmitting DC has lower losses because there is no inductive component to the losses.  Transforming voltages is much easier with AC because we can use a simple transformer.  DC is easily generated by a DC dynamo rather than a AC alternator. Switching of DC is harder too, transmission lines can use a single conductor and the planet as a return.  -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-voltage_direct_current

Comment: To be honest I didn't really investigate the transmition topic, I just remember seeing a documentation about the early 20th century when Tesla started providing AC to the households where before DC transmition was only possible in a range of about 800m around the "power-plant". Maybe that changed with HVDC

Answer (score 0):

The sinusoidal waveform is by design. not by conequence of simple harmonic motion. electrons have verry low mass and so flow easily in metal conductors.

The sinusoidal waveform and use of three phases allows the electricty to drive induction motors which being brushless are very durable and quiet running. it also allows the use of transformers to change the voltage.

Tranfromers having no moving parts, or active electronics are also very durable.

You do get something simple harminic motion in radio antennas, but power transmission lines are balanced so the induction and capacitance effects seen in antennas aren'r present to the same extent.